# How do I deploy the source code of my site to the hosting provider

Tags: deployment, hosting, web-deployment, web-hosting

I created a site in ASP.NET on Visual Studio.
I want to upload it to my website.
How do I connect my source code to my hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Select "Publish".
3. Double Click on FTP/FTPS Server.
4. Fill up the following details:

   1. Server: You can get the server name after logging into your hosting account or contact support and ask them
   2. Site path: URL of website without "https://"
   3. Destination URL: URL of website without "https://"
   4. Select the check box "Passive mode"
   5. Username: FTP username
   6. Password: FTP password
5. Select "Finish".
6. Select "Publish" from the "Project Name: Publish" tab.